# Entity Framework Core 2.1 : The specified field 'Model' could not be found for property 'Model' on entity type 'BarCodeDevice'

Tags: c#-4.0, entity-framework-core

I need to use Code First approach to generate Database by Entity Framework Core 2.1 but I get this error:

```
The specified field 'Model' could not be found for property 'Model' on entity type 'BarCodeDevice'.
```

Here are the classes I have used to do so

```
public class BarCodeDevice
    {
        public int SerialNumber { get; set; }
        public string Model { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<ClientBarCodeDevice> ClientBarCodeDeviceList { get; set; }
    }
```

And the configuration class

```
public class BarCodeDeviceConfiguration : IEntityTypeConfiguration<BarCodeDevice>
    {
        public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<BarCodeDevice> builder)
        {
            builder.HasKey(x => x.SerialNumber);
            builder.Property(t => t.Model)
              .IsRequired()
              .HasField("Model");
        }
    }
```

And The DbContext Class

```
public class SegregationDbContext : DbContext, IDisposable
    {
        public SegregationDbContext(DbContextOptions<SegregationDbContext> options) : base(options)
        { }


        protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {                        
            modelBuilder.ApplyConfiguration(new BarCodeDeviceConfiguration());            
        }

        public DbSet<BarCodeDevice> BarCodeDevices { get; set; }
    }
```

And finally the configuration

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddDbContext<SegregationDbContext>(options => options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("Default")));
            services.AddMvc();
        }
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The problem is this fluent configuration line:

```
.HasField("Model")
```

`HasField` is used to specify the [backing field](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/backing-field) for the property being configured, when the backing field name does not conform to the [conventions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/backing-field#conventions).

But you `Model` property is auto property and there is no backing field called `Model`, hence the exception.

So either remove that line, e.g.

```
builder.Property(t => t.Model)
    .IsRequired();
```

or if you want to force using the backing field with unknown name (which is the case with auto properties), use `UsePropertyAccessMode` method instead, e.g.

```
builder.Property(t => t.Model)
    .IsRequired()
    .UsePropertyAccessMode(PropertyAccessMode.Field);
```